# Bitmap variable on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

How can I initialize bitmap in kotlin?

I'm currently doing the following:

```
var drawablex = Bitmap()

getBitmapSingle(Picasso.get(), imagelink)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({ bitmap ->
         drawablex = BitmapDrawable( bitmap)
    }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
```

... but I think its wrong.

Comment: You don't need to create an empty Bitmap. You can just do lateinit var drawablex : Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

**try this out**

```
val bitmap = assetsToBitmap("ic_launcher_background")


    private fun assetsToBitmap(fileName:String): Bitmap?{
        return try{
            val stream = assets.open(fileName)
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)
        }catch (e: IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }


    // Method to convert a bitmap to bitmap drawable
    private fun bitmapToDrawable(bitmap:Bitmap): BitmapDrawable {
        return BitmapDrawable(resources,bitmap)
    }
```